# Парсинг сайтов c AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, парсер

Есть задача парсинга данных с сайта Яндекс-метрики.

Беда в том, что почти все данные загружаются при помощи AJAX кнопками типа "показать еще". Как можно это реализовать. Что использовать. Код будет на php.

Comment: Вы хотите парсить данные при каждом запросе? Может разумнее загрузить их отдельным запросом, который запускается периодически и кэширует данные?

Comment: Возможно я не совсем понимаю. Планировал при запросе получить код страницы целиком и потом его обработать. Ваш вариант плохо понимаю, поясните?

Comment: Просто у вас запросов может быть очень много и они могут повторяться. Т.е. одновременно могут уходить множество одинаковых запросов. Можно запускать скрипт по крон, который будет запрашивать данные и сохранять куда-то в хранилище, откуда обслуживать уже конечных пользователей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный вариант: посмотреть, какие AJAX запросы выполняются, с какими параметрами и из них получать всю нужную информацию. Здесь требуется потратить время на исследование API, чтобы понять формат данных и их взаимодействие со страницей.

Если лень или это требует нерационально много времени для текущего проекта на первой версии, тогда используйте парсинг через реальный браузер (например при помощи Selenium) или же урезанную версию браузера с поддержкой Javascript, который работает в командной строке (для PHP есть библиотека [PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs), которая похоже основанная на оригинальном PhantomJs)

Comment: Заказчик требует именно через парсинг. Без API. (((

Answer (score 2):

берёте api и парсите `https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/` без проблем

Comment: Ниже ответил((( это не мое решение

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин просто скажите что за апи он заплатит меньше чем за код, который после обновления выкинет в топку.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать связку типа Selenium+PhantomJS. Почитайте документацию, там есть как эмулировать нажатия кнопок и всего прочего. Самое главное - выставьте задержку секунд в десять, чтоб Ajax-элементы успевали прогрузиться. А потом можете тащить данные

Comment: А как по скорости весь этот процесс? Предполагаю, что тратится приличное время?

Comment: Ну это смотря сколько и чего вы слить хотите. Я сливал данные по миллиону домов - полтора дня работало